# Set Property of ViewController from Another Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, selector, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to set a property (NSManagedObject) of a view controller in another storyboard and present it:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MySecondStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController* initialView = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
initialView.entity= self.entity;
initialView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:initialView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But when it gets to

```
initialView.entity= self.entity;
```

I get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setEntity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Interestingly,

```
MyViewController* initialView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
initialView.entity= self.entity;
```

works, but I can't load it because it should be instantiated by its storyboard.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace:

```
MyViewController* initialView = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

with:

```
MyViewController* initialView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ID"];
```

Last go to your second storyboard and go to your view controller. Set the storyboard ID to "ID".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have connected the MyViewcontroller to the correct storyboard view controller, and the story board is marked as initial.
then try casting like

```
MyViewController* initialView =(MyViewController *) [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```